# How to perform fwrite in a loop in c++

Tags: c++

Okay, here's my code that seems to fail and doesn't even write at least once, I fail to see what's actually wrong, could anyone point me in the correct direction?

My intention is to perform this write every 10 seconds on an infinite loop

```
FILE* pFile;
pFile = fopen("Hdd:\\LOGFile.txt", "w");
while(true) {
    DWORD TitleID = XamGetCurrentTitleId();
    std::ostringstream titleMessageSS;
    titleMessageSS << "Here's the current title we're on : " << TitleID << "\r";
    std::string titleMessage = titleMessageSS.str(); // get the string from the stream
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)titleMessage.size();
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    fwrite(titleMessage.c_str(), 1 , dwBytesToWrite, pFile);
    Sleep(10000);
}
fclose(pFile);
return NULL;
```

Comment: Exchange `1, dwBytesToWrite` in order: `fwrite(titleMessage.c_str(), dwBytesToWrite, 1, pFile);`. See the [`fwrite()` reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite). Also you should check error conditions after calling such operations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ None of which make a difference here.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well you're right, my c fu is quite rusty :) ...

Comment: @JamesKanze - what's the actual problem here then?

Comment: You could try throwing an `std::fflush(pFile);` in there, just in case you are examining the file while the data is still in the buffer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, you could sort of be right.  He should check for error conditions after the `fclose` (and of course, there's no guarantee that an external program could see the data before then anyway, unless he explicitly flushes it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should call `fflush(pFile);` before your call to `Sleep`; 
but you should better use C++ `std::ostream`  (and use `std::flush` manipulator).

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it doesn't write?  Is the file empty after the
program stops.

What I suspect is that you're looking at the output file before the
program has stopped.  The stream types (both C++ and C) are normally
buffered; `fwrite` copies the data to a local buffer, and only transfers
it to the OS (system function `write` under Unix) when the buffer is
full, when you explicitly flush it (see `fflush`) or when the file is
closed.  This is, for example, why we have to check for output errors
after `fclose()`.